# Extract particular string from string using java

Tags: java

```
<tr>Test1</tr>Test String1
<tr>Test2</tr>Test String2
<tr>Test3</tr>Test String3
<tr>Test4</tr>Test String4
```

I need to fetch string (include tag) which are tag with `<tr>` and `</tr>`

After extract I need to store those value in `HashMap` like below

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("<tr>Test1</tr>", "");
map.put("<tr>Test2</tr>", "");
map.put("<tr>Test3</tr>", "");
map.put("<tr>Test4</tr>", "");
```

How to do that?

Comment: Depending on how robust your solution needs to be, you can use simple string operations... to using regex... to parsing the `xml` and using `XPath` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java).

Comment: I think my question not similar with attached link

Comment: Can some one give me that regex which will give that list of string